# WPF - Flat Tree View Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core, wpf-controls

I'm trying to build a flat tree view like this:

[image: A flat tree view.]

I have deeply nested hierarchical data:

```
- A1
  - B1
    - ...
      - X1
        - Y1
          - ...
            - AJ1
      - X2
        - Y2
          - Z2
- A2
  - B2
    - ...
- ...
```

I expect long "chains", but not many branches.

I'd like to display this data like this:

```
<StackPanel>
  <!-- A1 -->
  <WrapPanel>
    <TextBlock>A1</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>B1</TextBlock>
    <!-- ... -->
    <StackPanel>
      <WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock>X1</TextBlock>
        <!-- ... -->
        <TextBlock>AJ1</TextBlock>
      </WrapPanel>

      <WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock>X2</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>Y2</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>Z2</TextBlock>
      </WrapPanel>
    <StackPanel>
  </WrapPanel>

  <!-- A2 -->
  <WrapPanel>
    <TextBlock>A2</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>...</TextBlock>
  </WrapPanel>

  <!-- ... -->
</StackPanel>
```

In other words: If a node has zero or one children, it should just be displayed alongside its parent in a `WrapPanel`, if a node has more than one child, it should display each child as a new `WrapPanel` inside of a `StackPanel`.

I tried using a regular `TreeView`, however this forces each child to be contained inside of its parent (so you can't flatten the tree).

At this point I'm not sure if I'm using TreeView wrong, or if I'd have to write my own `ItemsControl`. I already looked at the MSDN docs for `ItemsControl` but as of right now it's not immediately obvious how I would use it/ which methods I'd need to implement.

**Edit**: I uploaded a repo with sample data [to GitHub](https://github.com/fschoenberger/WpfFlatTreeViewExample).

Comment: This can be done using TreeView, but for the example to work for you, I need to debug it on your collection. If you provide a solution that forms your collection, then I will try to use it to create the representation you need. The solution is best provided via GitHub.

Comment: @EldHasp Thanks so much, I uploaded the code to GitHub (https://github.com/fschoenberger/WpfFlatTreeViewExample). The project visualizes on the left what I want to build and on the right what I currently have :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to get, then here is a solution:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace FlatTreeViewExample
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(MoveViewModel), typeof(IEnumerable<MoveViewModel>))]
    public class MoveVmToItemsSourceConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            MoveViewModel? currentVM = value as MoveViewModel;
            while (currentVM?.Children.Count > 0)
            {
                if (currentVM.Children.Count == 1)
                {
                    currentVM = currentVM.Children[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    return currentVM.Children;
                }
            }
            return Array.Empty<MoveViewModel>();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #region Singleton
        private MoveVmToItemsSourceConverter() { }
        public static MoveVmToItemsSourceConverter Instance { get; } = new();
        #endregion
    }

    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(MoveVmToItemsSourceConverter))]
    public class MoveVmToItemsSourceExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return MoveVmToItemsSourceConverter.Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace FlatTreeViewExample
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(MoveViewModel), typeof(string))]
    public class MoveVmToTextConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            MoveViewModel? currentVM = value as MoveViewModel;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(currentVM?.Text);
            while (currentVM?.Children.Count == 1)
            {
                currentVM = currentVM.Children[0];
                builder.Append(currentVM.Text);
            }
            return builder.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #region Singleton
        private MoveVmToTextConverter() { }
        public static MoveVmToTextConverter Instance { get; } = new();
        #endregion

    }
    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(MoveVmToTextConverter))]
    public class MoveVmToTextSourceExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return MoveVmToTextConverter.Instance;
        }
    }

}
```

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="FlatTreeViewExample.MoveExplorer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FlatTreeViewExample"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MoveExplorerVM}">
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Moves}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={local:MoveVmToItemsSource}}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={local:MoveVmToTextSource}}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</UserControl>
```

**An example of using a ListBox** to create a list of items in the context of a TreeItem, including adding a context menu for each list item:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace FlatTreeViewExample
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(MoveViewModel), typeof(List<MoveViewModel>))]
    public class MoveVmToListVMConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            MoveViewModel currentVM = (MoveViewModel) value;
            List<MoveViewModel> list = new List<MoveViewModel>(10) { currentVM };
            while (currentVM?.Children.Count == 1)
            {
                currentVM = currentVM.Children[0];
                list.Add(currentVM);
            }
            return list;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #region Singleton
        private MoveVmToListVMConverter() { }
        public static MoveVmToListVMConverter Instance { get; } = new();
        #endregion

    }

    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(MoveVmToTextConverter))]
    public class MoveVmToListVMExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return MoveVmToListVMConverter.Instance;
        }
    }

}
```

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="FlatTreeViewExample.MoveExplorer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FlatTreeViewExample"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MoveExplorerVM}">
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Moves}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={local:MoveVmToItemsSource}}">
                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={local:MoveVmToText}}"/>-->
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={local:MoveVmToListVM}}">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MoveViewModel}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}">
                                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, StringFormat='Hi, {0}!'}"/>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is almost exactly what I need! How would I go about adding a context menu to each move (or selecting individual moves)?

Comment: @FredericSchönberger, Please clarify, I don’t quite understand what you want to receive? In my version, a common text is created for all elements with one child. For example: «1. e4c62. d4d53. e5c54. c3Nc». You need that each point be a separate element «1. e4c6», «2. d4d5», «3. e5c5», «4. c3Nc». And each of them needs the ability to create a context menu.
Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @FredericSchönberger, See at the new example I added to my answer.

Comment: This is amazing and exactly what I needed, thank you so much!

Btw, I think there's a typo in your second example, it should probably be `[ValueConversion(typeof(MoveViewModel), typeof(List<MoveViewModel>))]`.

Comment: @FredericSchönberger, Correctly noted.
I'll make corrections to my answer.